# Laravel: Complicated Eloquent Relationship - hasManyThrough or belongsToMany approach?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have three Models (Organization, User, Visit) and 4 tables (organizations, users, organization_user, visits). I'm trying to get the accumulative total of user visits for an Organization.

```
Organization
------------
id,
name

User
---------
id,
name

Organization_User
----------------
id,
organization_id,
user_id

Visit
--------------
id,
user_id
views
```

Just to clarify, there is no Organization_User model, that is just the pivot table used by User and Organization:

```
$organization->belongsToMany('User');
$user->belongsToMany('Organization');
```

I could query all the user_ids from the pivot table by group_id, and then get all the visits for each user_id, but what's the more Eloquent approach?

A User hasMany Visits and a Visit belongsTo a User. A Visit doesn't belong to an Organization.

Comment: I can see no relation between visit and user and user can have many organizations - how do you determine to which organization given visit record belongs? Or should a visit linked to a user A be counted for all organizations this user belongs to?

Comment: A User hasMany visits and a Visit belongsTo User. A visit doesn't belong to an Organization but only a User. What I'm trying to do is get the accumulative total of visits by Users in a Organization.

Comment: do you consider to add `visit_amount` in  `Organization_User` ?

Comment: Organization_User is only a simple relational Pivot table since a User can belongToMany Organizations and Organizations can belongToMany Users. It is not meant to and should not keep track of visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using whereIn(). Basically with no change to my current relationship setup...to get accumulative views I did this:

```
$org = Organization::find($org_id);
return DB::table('visits')->whereIn('user_id', $org->users->modelKeys())->sum("views");
```

The modelKeys() returns all the user ids tied to that Organization. Then I get the sum of all the views for those users.

*Note it's also important to use Organization::find and not DB::table('organization') in order to maintain the Eloquent relationship. Otherwise $organization->users will give an error.

Comment: I have a question, does `$org->users->modelKeys()` get the IDs of those users related to that specific organization? Or is it the IDs of the organizations?

Comment: @pathros it returns an array of the primary keys of all the users related to that single organization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want a 'Has Many Through' relationship like so:

```
class Organization extends Model
{
    public function visits()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Visit', 'App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you could call `count()`.

[Laravel 5.1 doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: I don't think that works because User doesn't have an organization_id because a user can belong to many organizations. So it's relationship is though a pivot table (Organization_User).

Comment: There are many ways you can accomplish what you're trying to do with the appropriate table structures for any given solution. Are you locked in to the current table structures?

Comment: Yes it is already an active architecture. Also Visits is it's own large table of meta data...more than just visit counts.